# What are data requirements for FP-Growth in Weka?

Tags: java, data-mining, weka

I'd like to use FP-Growth association rule algorithm on my dataset (model) in Weka.

Unfortunately, this algorithm is greyed out. What are preconditions I have to meet in order to make use of it?

Comment: Why people are downgrading? C'mon, at least leave a comment...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer/solution:

1. Each algorithm that Weka implements has some sort of a summary info associated with it. In order to see it from the GUI, one has to click on algorithm (or filter) options and then click once more on `Capabilities` button. Then a small popup will show up containing some info regarding particular algorithm.
2. In case of `FPGrowth` - model attributes needs to be of `binary` type. In my case I had a mix od nominal and numeric parameters. I had to apply `NominalToBinary` filter which converted my nominal attributes to binary values. Then I had to apply flter `NumericToBinary` with selected option `ignoreClass` set to `true`.

This has helped me to "unlock" `FPGrowth` in Weka.

Comment: Here's a slight longer explanation: "FP-Growth algorithm works for boolean values only. Hence, the attributes of the dataset can have only true or false values. If you are using different type of attributes (numeric, string etc.), it looks disabled." http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/FP-GROWTH-Algorithm-td23554.html

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @ŁukaszBachman answer: 
You need to set class to "No Class" before applying filter operation. If you are using weka java api, then you need to add `data.setClassIndex(-1)` to your java code.

For example: To perform Nominal To Binary in Java:

```
        NominalToBinary nn = new NominalToBinary();
        nn.setInputFormat(Data);
        Data.setClassIndex(-1);
        Data = Filter.useFilter(Data, nn);
```